# Linq dynamic where Func<T, TS>

Tags: c#, linq, generics, entity-framework-core

So basically I have these objects:

```
public interface ISearchVector {
    public NpgsqlTsVector SearchVector { get; set; }
}

public class EntityA {
    public EntityB Property { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB : ISearchVector {
    public NpgsqlTsVector SearchVector { get; set; }
}
```

EntityA has a Property of type EntityB;
EntityB implements ISearchVector;

What I want is basically perform a where on EntityA.Property.SearchVector like this:

```
queryable<EntityA>.Where(x => x.Property.SearchVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("english", "search")));
```

What I tried:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Search<T, TS>(
            this IQueryable<T> queryable,
            string text,
            Func<T, TS> prop) where TS : ISearchVector
        {
            var q = queryable
                .Include(prop)
                .Where(x => x[prop].SearchVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("english", text))); // struggling here, how to access prop inside x (x[prop])
            return q;
        }
```

I would call this function like this:

```
dbContext.Set<EntityA>().Search("", x => x.Property);
```

Hope it's clear and open to suggestions

Thank you

Comment: Using `T` as a class name is a really bad idea.  And it make it hard to see that the issue is that inside of `Search` you've defined a generic type `T` that is not the same as the class `T`.  And that applies to `TS` as well.

Comment: I used T just to simplify the example, it doesn't have this name

Comment: why not simply .Where(x => prop(x).SearchVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("english", text))); ? Keep in mind that IQueriable requires Expression<Func<a,b,c>> instead of Func<a,b,c>

Comment: If the names are not `T` and `TS` then use the real names in the example or at least use something that does not clash with the defined generic type names.

Comment: Fixed class names